# FreeMarker template not detected in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, freemarker, template-engine

I`m trying to build an app with spring boot using freemarker as template engine.
I am using Gradle.

This is the @RestController class

```
@RestController
public class CodeController {
    private CodeService codeService;

    public CodeController(@Autowired CodeService codeService) {
        this.codeService = codeService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/code/{id}")
    public String getCode(Model model, @PathVariable int id) {
        List<CodeSnippet> codeSnippets = codeService.getCodeSnippet(id);

        model.addAttribute("codeSnippets", codeSnippets);
        System.out.println(codeSnippets);
        return "getcode";

    }

}
```

And this is the FreeMarker template file getcode.ftlh

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Code</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <style>
        #load_date {
            color: green;
        }

        pre {
            margin-top: 0;
            border: solid black 1px;
            background-color: lightgray;
            padding: .3em
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<#list codeSniptets as codeSnippte>
    <span id=\"load_date\">${codeSnippte.date}</span>
    <pre id=\"code_snippet\">${codeSnippte.code}</pre>
</#list>

</body>
</html>
```

Spring boot should load the codeSnipptets list to the template.
However, I just receive "getcode" string as the output instead of the HTML page when the page loaded with a browser or postman.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already configures FreeMarkerViewResolver

and instead of RestController use Controller

Comment: Awesome! Need to use @Controller instead.